# jQuery - chaining a native function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone explain why I can chain a native JavaScript function to a jQuery function like so:

```
$('#search').val().replace("00:00:00", "")
```

In this case, replace is the native JavaScript function.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Thanks

Comment: Definition added. I guess because .val() returns a string, and replace() works on a string, it just...works

Comment: yea thats the only explanation.

Comment: @ Jamie Carruthers: add your comment as the answer to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case `val()` must be returning a `string` value and hence `replace` works as expected.  It's no different than calling a function which returns a `string` and chaining that

```
function example() {
  return "foo";
}

example().replace("00:00:00", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

As Jamie said the functions get evaluated left to right. So val() returns a type string, which has the method `replace`.
The reason jquery functions are all chainable is because they return a reference to the original object created by the selector each time they return.
With the exceptions of val(), text(), html() and a few others.

Answer (score 1):

It's because:

```
$('#search').val().replace("00:00:00", "")
```

will evaluate to:

```
"some string".replace("00:00:00", "")
```

which is nothing special. It basically always comes down to evaluating the functions from left to right, also in cases like:

```
$('#search').eq(0).val().replace("00:00:00", "")
<jQuery obj>.val().replace("00:00:00", "")
"some string".replace("00:00:00", "")
```